# int vs int32 return value

Tags: go

I am running into an issue, which seems to be related to `int32` vs `int` data type. My program is returning different values on different environments.

For example, on go playground, I notice the value returned is -4 (which is expected value). But the same on Leetcode with same input returns a value of 4294967292. While it returned this value, when I print it, I get -4 (see output added later).

I tried casting to `int32(res)` but didn't help. Also didn't find any directly related in textbook. Please help me understand why this is different on go playground vs Leetcode.

https://play.golang.org/p/qXMd9frlhbe

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v", singleNumber([]int{-2,-2,1,1,-3,1,-3,-3,-4,-2}))
}

func singleNumber(nums []int) int {
    sum := make([]int, 32)

    for _, v := range nums {
        for i := 0; i < 32; i++ {
            if sum[i] != 0 {
                sum[i] += 1 & (v >> uint32(i))
            } else {
                sum[i] = 1 & (v >> uint32(i))
            }
        }
    }

    res := 0 
    for k, v := range sum {
        if (v%3) != 0 {
            res |= (v%3) << uint32(k) 
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("res %+v\n", res)
    return res
}
```

Same on Leetcode gives the output:

```
Input:
[-2,-2,1,1,-3,1,-3,-3,-4,-2]
Output:
4294967292
Expected:
-4
Stdout:
res -4
```

Comment: It might be something with how the OS operates 32 bytes vs 64. Instead of casting to a uint32 try just an uint and let go decide how to handle, seems like some kind of overflow, uint32 max value is 4294967295
https://goplay.space/#dBEy8OeNk37

Comment: `int` in Go is equivalent on `int64` on `x64` systems and is equivalent of `int32` on `x32` systems.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian, a nitpick: please be careful with that `x32` name: technically it describes a particular [Linux ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) which has 64-bit wide ints while having 32-bit wide pointers. If you want to refer to a "usual" 32-bit system, it's better to just say 32-bit or something like `i386`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The textbook you are looking for is

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> A numeric type represents sets of integer or floating-point values.
>   The predeclared architecture-independent numeric types are:
>
> ```
> uint32 set of all unsigned 32-bit integers (0 to 4294967295)
> uint64 set of all unsigned 64-bit integers (0 to 18446744073709551615)
>
> int32  set of all signed 32-bit integers (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
> int64  set of all signed 64-bit integers (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
> ```
>
> There is also a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
> uint either 32 or 64 bits
> int  same size as uint
> ```

---

Check the size of type `int`. On the Go Playground it's 4 bytes or 32 bits.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("arch", runtime.GOARCH)
    fmt.Println("int", unsafe.Sizeof(int(0)))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2A6ODvhb1Dx

Output (Playground):

```
arch amd64p32
int 4
```

Run the program in your (LeetCode) environment. It's likely 8 bytes or 64 bits.

For example, in my environment,

Output (Local):

```
arch amd64
int 8
```

---

Here are some fixes to your code,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOARCH)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", singleNumber([]int{-2, -2, 1, 1, -3, 1, -3, -3, -4, -2}))
}

func singleNumber(nums []int) int {
    sum := make([]int, 64)

    for _, v := range nums {
        for i := range sum {
            sum[i] += 1 & (v >> uint(i))
        }
    }

    res := 0
    for k, v := range sum {
        if (v % 3) != 0 {
            res |= (v % 3) << uint(k)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("res %+v\n", res)
    return res
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/kaoSuesu2Oj

Output (Playground):

```
amd64p32
res -4
-4
```

Output (Local):

```
amd64
res -4
-4
```

Comment: TIL - this is interesting as this makes the code platform dependent (by this I mean int size being dependent on the platform). Thanks for your answer.